# what does "Yesterday" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “My copy is terrible!” he writes in a slightly panicked email. “I need copy that converts like crazy and I need it **yesterday**!”

what does *yesterday* mean  here?

Comment: The word *yesterday* is not special by itself here. You can read "I need it *yesterday*!" as "I wish I would have had it since yesterday!"

Comment: I need it really soon.  How soon?  I'll tell you: I don't need it in two hours.  I don't need it in one hour.  I don't need it in ten minutes.  I need it yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plain English, the word "yesterday" refers to the day before "today".

Obviously, the speaker can't have something given to him before today - not without a time machine, at least. It this case, his use of the word "yesterday" is an example of exaggeration or *hyperbole*. Logically, he would say "I need it RIGHT NOW", but instead he goes beyond that and says "I need it YESTERDAY" to convey how urgently he needs the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, this doesn't make sense in English. In this case it's a figure of speech and means that something's late or overdue.